# How do I access a private Container Registry from IBM Cloud Delivery Pipeline (Tekton, dockerconfigjson)

Tags: ibm-cloud, tekton, tekton-pipelines, delivery-pipeline

I am trying to use a container image from a private container registry in one of my tasks.

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: echo-hello-world
spec:
  steps:
    - name: echo
      image: de.icr.io/reporting/status:latest
      command:
        - echo
      args:
        - "Hello World"
```

But when I run this task within an IBM Cloud Delivery Pipeline (Tekton) the image can not be pulled

```
 message: 'Failed to pull image "de.icr.io/reporting/status:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "de.icr.io/reporting/status:latest": failed to resolve reference "de.icr.io/reporting/status:latest": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized'
```

I read several tutorials and blogs, but so far couldn't find a solution. This is probably what I need to accomplish, so that the IBM Cloud Delivery Pipeline (Tekton) can access my private container registry: https://tekton.dev/vault/pipelines-v0.15.2/auth/#basic-authentication-docker

So far I have created a secret.yaml file in my .tekton directory:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: basic-user-pass
 annotations:
   tekton.dev/docker-0: https://de.icr.io # Described below
type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
stringData:
  username: $(params.DOCKER_USERNAME)
  password: $(params.DOCKER_PASSWORD)
```

I am also creating a ServiceAccount

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
 name: default-runner
secrets:
 - name: basic-user-pass
```

And in my trigger definition I telling the pipeline to use the `default-runner` ServiceAccount:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
metadata:
  name: theTemplateTrigger
spec:
  resourcetemplates:
  - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
    kind: PipelineRun
    metadata:
      name: pipelinerun-$(uid)
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: default-runner
      pipelineRef:
        name: hello-goodbye
```

Comment: You typically use an API key (user or service ID) to access the container registry, using iamapikey as username and the API key as password

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik. But how to make the apikey available for my Tekton based delivery pipelines. And ideally I want to use the API key that I stored in Secret Manager and inject it into the Pipeline.

Comment: The basic auth secret type won't do, you need some dockercfg secret instead. You can take tekton out of the equation for now: how do you start Pods pulling from that registry? You would probably set a docker secret, and allow some ServiceAccounts to use it. Or refer to that secret in your Pods definition. The same would apply here for your Task: set pipeline SA imagePullSecrets, or define this in your Tasks' pod template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to pass my API key to my IBM Cloud Delivery Pipeline (Tekton) and the tasks in my pipeline are now able to pull container images from my private container registry.

This is my working trigger template:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
metadata:
  name: theTemplateTrigger
spec:
  params:
    - name: pipeline-dockerconfigjson
      description: dockerconfigjson for images used in .pipeline-config.yaml
      default: "eyJhdXRocyI6e319" # ie. {"auths":{}} base64 encoded
  resourcetemplates:
    - apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      data:
        .dockerconfigjson: $(tt.params.pipeline-dockerconfigjson)
      metadata:
        name: pipeline-pull-secret
      type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson      
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      metadata:
        name: pipelinerun-$(uid)
      spec:
        pipelineRef:
          name: hello-goodbye
        podTemplate:
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: pipeline-pull-secret
```

It first defines a parameter called `pipeline-dockerconfigjson`:

```
  params:
    - name: pipeline-dockerconfigjson
      description: dockerconfigjson for images used in .pipeline-config.yaml
      default: "eyJhdXRocyI6e319" # ie. {"auths":{}} base64 encoded
```

The second part turns the value passed into this parameter into a Kubernetes secret:

```
    - apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      data:
        .dockerconfigjson: $(tt.params.pipeline-dockerconfigjson)
      metadata:
        name: pipeline-pull-secret
      type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

And this secret is then pushed into the `imagePullSecrets` field of the PodTemplate.

The last step is to populate the parameter with a valid `dockerconfigjson` and this can be accomplished within the Delivery Pipeline UI (IBM Cloud UI).

To create a valid `dockerconfigjson` for my registry `de.icr.io` I had to use the following kubectl command:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry mysecret \
 --dry-run=client \
 --docker-server=de.icr.io  \
 --docker-username=iamapikey \                     
 --docker-password=<MY_API_KEY> \
 --docker-email=<MY_EMAIL> \
 -o yaml
```

and then within the output there is a valid base64 encoded `.dockerconfigjson` field.

Answer (score 2):

Please also note that there is a public catalog of sample tekton tasks:
https://github.com/open-toolchain/tekton-catalog/tree/master/container-registry

More on IBM Cloud Continuous Delivery Tekton:
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/ibm-cloud-continuous-delivery-tekton-pipelines-tools-and-resources

Tektonized Toolchain Templates: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/toolchain-templates-with-tekton-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

The secret you created (type basic-auth) would not allow Kubelet to pull your Pods images.

The [doc mentions](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/auth.md#configuring-basic-auth-authentication-for-docker) those secrets are meant to provision some configuration, inside your tasks containers runtime. Which may then be used during your build jobs, pulling or pushing images to registries.

Although Kubelet needs [some different configuration](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/auth.md#configuring-docker-authentication-for-docker) (eg: type dockercfg), to authenticate when pulling images / starting containers.

Comment: Thank you, SYN ... this morning I finally figured it out and I will type an answer to my question here. As always, once you see the solution it's kind of clear. Thanks for pointing out that I was on the wrong track.